# jQuery how to replace :last selector if I need its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am upgrading my code for the latest jQuery, but I stumbled into a problem with deprecated `:last` selector. In most cases, all I needed to do was to delete it and slap `.last()` after, but I have a problem with this:

```
$('#someId tr:last textarea').each(function(){
    //some code
});
```

where `:last` is not the ultimate thing I want to select. I don't even know how to form the google question for this. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still [continue selecting](https://api.jquery.com/find/) after `.last()` (that's basic functionality of jquery, I advice to read up on it if you want to continue to use it) or simply use css selector `:last-child`

```
$('#someId tr:last-child textarea').each(function(){
    //some code
});
```

or

```
$('#someId tr').last().find('textarea').each(function(){
    //some code
});
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. I must have had a blackout or something.